# Matplotlib errorbar not centered on marker

Tags: python, matplotlib

What's the trick to get the errorbar centered on the marker when using `errorbar`?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.errorbar([1],[1],[0.1],fmt='k^',capsize=5,capthick=2,ms=9,markerfacecolor='none',mew=2)
plt.show()
```

This is very annoying when trying to make presentation-quality plots with errorbars.  All my errorbars seem to be a pixel or two off-centered.  This affects the legend as well.  I tried various marker sizes and linewidths, but they are never centered correctly.  Using matplotlib 1.2.1 on Mac OX 10.8.4.   Tried on mpl 1.3.1 and got the same results.

[image: Errobar bar obviously not in the center of the marker]
[image]

Comment: Does this happen with newer versions of mpl?  Either 1.3.1 or 1.4.0rc4?  I know some work went by to fix pixel snapping.

Comment: @tcaswell I just tried with 1.3.1 and got the same result

Comment: Can you make a github issue for this?  I can also reproduce in on close-to-master.

Comment: interestingly mine are off-center the _other_ way and the `snap` kwarg seems to have no effect.

Comment: Made a github issue.  Hard to believe I'm the first one to find this apparent bug, as it's fairly obvious.  Oh well.  Thanks for confirming it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Confirmed bug.  Github issue created, and flagged to be fixed in MPL 1.4.x

Comment: I can confirm this is fixed as of MPL 1.5.1-1 (Windows)

Comment: The bugreport is here - and it is not fixed yet: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/3400 - However, saving the figure as PDF will not result in the errorbars being centred correctly.