# matplotlib offset errorbar in interactive plot with "capthick" option

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am making an errorbar plot using the matplotlib error bar function, with the "capthick" argument.  When I set "capthick=2", in the interactive plot the errorbar cap is offset to the left.  When I save the figure, however, the errorbar cap is plotted correctly.  Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug?

**Code to reproduce the problem:**

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

xx  = np.arange(5)
err = np.ones(5) * 0.25

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5,2))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax.errorbar(xx, np.ones(5),   yerr=err, marker='d')
ax.errorbar(xx, np.ones(5)+1, yerr=err, marker='d', capthick=2)
ax.errorbar(xx, np.ones(5)+2, yerr=err, marker='d', linewidth=2, capthick=2)

plt.show()
plt.draw()
plt.savefig('errorbar_offset.png')
```

**Figure 1:** Screenshot of the plot produced by the code above.  The issue is in the green errorbar caps, which are shifted to the left.  Additionally, the thick red lines are not centered on the symbols.

[image]

**Figure 2:** image that was saved using plt.savefig().  This figure looks OK.

[image]

**Details:**
matplotlib version = 1.4.0
ipython version = 2.3.1

**Relevant previous posts:**
[Matplotlib errorbar not centered on marker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25451871/matplotlib-errorbar-not-centered-on-marker?lq=1)

Comment: Unable to reproduce the problem using matplotlib 1.4.2.

Comment: I updated to matplotlib 1.4.2 and the problem remains.  To be more specific, I can view the issue by taking a screen-shot of the interactive plot produced by the code above, and zooming into one thick green cap.  The thick cap is 6 pixels wide: relative to the vertical errorbar line, there are three green pixels to the left, one pixel directly above, and two pixels to the right, creating the offset errorbar cap.  If there is any way to post an image (given my lack of reputation), this would be much clearer.

Comment: If you can include a link to the image on a file-sharing site, I'll post it. (Start comment with @unutbu to ping me.)

Comment: @ubuntu You should be able to see the screen-shot image here on Google+ (permissions set to "shared publicly").  I will take this image down after you are able to view it and post here.
https://plus.google.com/114018090859195320847/posts/RFaYVFGBYik?pid=6095051674430961746&oid=114018090859195320847

Comment: @ubunto Here is "Figure 2".  Sorry, I should have uploaded these at the same time.  I appreciate your help!
https://plus.google.com/114018090859195320847/posts/YPTEWdymAfx?pid=6095057062856191714&oid=114018090859195320847

Comment: What does `mpl.get_backend()` return? and (though I don't know if it matters) what OS?

Comment: @unutbu mpl.get_backend() prints: u'Qt4Agg'
os: Scientific Linux release 6.1 (Carbon)

Comment: This is an [open issue](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/3400). (Found by going to https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues and searching for `is:issue is:open capthick`.)